# Access document properties from a Mongoose Model using Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I use Mongoose with Typescript and want to acess the properties from a Model. Given this example **UserModel**

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const userSchema: Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
});

export const UserModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I want to access the **username** after fetching the user

```
const user: Document | null = await UserModel.findById(id);
const username: string = (user as Document).username;
```

but due to the fact `Document` is an interface, I can't accesss the property from the **UserModel**. How can I access it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, that you create an interface for your `User` like this:

```
export interface IUserDocument extends mongoose.Document {
    username: string;
}
```

afterward you can define your model with the following:

```
export const UserModel = mongoose.model<IUserDocument>('User', userSchema);
```

If you then get a `IUserDocument` you can easily access the username property on the found document like this:

```
const user: IUserDocument | null = await UserModel.findById(id);
const username: string = user.username;
```